# Find next and replace in summer-note editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, editor

I want java-script code to add custom button for find next and replace in summer-note editor like image given below -

[image]

I get success to replace text globally by using "gi" regex and also get success to replace all words one by one using "i" regex. But I am not able to skip word using find next and then replace next word.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post what have you achieved so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a function into your regex replace statement, in which you can replace only a certain nth match in the method shown here. When someone clicks `Find Next` for the first time on a new search, it should create a variable to keep track of `n`, setting it equal to 1 to start with. Each time they click `Find Next` again, increase your value of `n`. When they do click `Replace`, call `replaceNth` with that value, then increase the value of `n` and move on to the next result.

The first call here shows that you can use this function as a catchall - if you don't pass `n`, it will just replace everything. If you do pass `n`, it will replace that one match.

```js
function replaceNth(str, rgx, replacement, n){
  if(n) {
    let matchIndex = 0
    return str.replace(rgx, match => {
      return ++matchIndex == n ? replacement : match
    })
  } else {
    return str.replace(rgx, replacement)
  }
}

let sampleText = document.querySelector('p').textContent

console.log(replaceNth(sampleText, /cow/gi, 'MOO'))

console.log(replaceNth(sampleText, /cow/gi, 'MOO', 2))
```

```html
<p>This is sample cow text with the word cow placed repeatedly cow within it.</p>
```